# uninitialized constant Request (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, initializer, gibbon

I get this error: `/LiveToChallenge/config/initializers/gibbon.rb:1:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gibbon::Request (NameError)` when I try to start the server `rails server`.

**app/config/initializers/gibbon.rb**

```
require 'gibbon'
Gibbon::Request.api_key = "24e4a2233cd34debb76ed083dc3f8b5379-us8"
Gibbon::Request.timeout = 15
```

I followed [gibbon gem](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) instructions, which seemed simple enough. Maybe I'm missing something besides just `gem install gibbon` and adding `api_key` to initializer?

The gem is installed as `gibbon (2.2.2, 2.2.1, 1.2.1)`

And as added measure I put `gem gibbon` in the gemfile and ran `bundle install`

This problem is part of a [larger problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949045/how-to-save-email-to-subscribers-with-checkbox) I've been working on solving.

Comment: Can you try doing it with this syntax: Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: "your_api_key", timeout: 15) ?

Comment: do this and then try to declare the variables under it. It seems like the variable is still not initialized when you try to give it values

Comment: No unfortunately same error even with variable declared under it in file. Thanks for trying @HristoGeorgiev

Comment: you probably might need to put `require 'gibbon'` at the top of that file, ruby somehow can't find the `Gibbon::Request` constant, so that means it's probably not loaded by rails

Comment: @bjhaid I added it as you suggested, but still no luck. Updated question

Comment: you should have `gem 'gibbon'` in your Gemfile and then run `bundle install` after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced same issue with `gibbon 2.0` version as it has updated some methods for initializations then i tried a previous version & it worked but first You should try it this way :

```
gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: "MailChimp_API_Key")
gibbon.timeout = 10
```

If no luck with this in app/config/initializers/gibbon.rb then you can try to do this direct in the controller just before using gibbon to retrieve or add list stuff for testing.

Comment: Got it! Had to move the code directly into the controller as you suggested :]

Answer (score 0):

You should add the gem to the rails Gemfile. Then rails will take care of the `require 'gibbon'` for you.

Edit: `gem install gibbon` will just install the gem on your system. Rails won't know that it is needed unless you add it to the Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks Sammygadd for your help! I added `require 'gibbon'`, ran bundle install again with `gem gibbon` but still same error :/

Comment: When you run `bundle install` do you see gibbon listed in the output?

Comment: Yes sir I did. Problem persisted

Comment: Sorry about the basic questions, but did you add the gem to a group e.g. test or production and your running in another mode e.g. development?

Comment: No problem sammygadd. It is not in a production, test, or development group. It is with my main list of gems